# Creating Worst-Case Scenario for QuickSort using Middle Pivot in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, quick-sort

I've implemented a solution to generate the worst-case scenario for QuickSort using the middle pivot strategy in Java. The goal is to rearrange an input array to produce the worst performance during sorting.

Here's the code I've written:

```java
public class WorstCaseForMiddlePivotQuickSort<E extends Comparable<? super E>> {
    private static <E extends Comparable<? super E>> int partition(List<E> arr, int low, int high) {
        int middlePivotIndex = (low + high) / 2;
        E pivot = arr.get(middlePivotIndex);
        
        int i = low;
        int j = high;
        
        while (i <= j) {
            while (arr.get(i).compareTo(pivot) < 0) {
                i++;
            }
            while (arr.get(j).compareTo(pivot) > 0) {
                j--;
            }
            
            if (i <= j) {
                Collections.swap(arr, i, j);
                i++;
                j--;
            }
        }
        
        return i;
    }
    
    
    private static <E extends Comparable<? super E>> void quickSortUsingMiddlePivot(List<E> arr, int low, int high, List<Integer> partitionIndexHistory) {
        if (low >= high) {
            return;
        }
        int partitionIndex = partition(arr, low, high);
        partitionIndexHistory.add(partitionIndex);
        quickSortUsingMiddlePivot(arr, low, partitionIndex - 1, partitionIndexHistory);
        quickSortUsingMiddlePivot(arr, partitionIndex + 1, high, partitionIndexHistory);
    }
    
    public static <E extends Comparable<? super E>> List<E> generateWorstCaseForQuickSortPivotPoint(List<E> input, Map<Integer, Integer> currentIndexToPreviousIndexMapping) {
        List<E> reverseOrdered = new ArrayList<>(input);
        reverseOrdered.sort(Collections.reverseOrder());
        List<E> worstCase = new ArrayList<>(Collections.nCopies(reverseOrdered.size(), null));
        int inOrderCount = 0;
        while (inOrderCount < worstCase.size()) {
            int whereToPut = (reverseOrdered.size() - inOrderCount - 1) / 2;
            if (worstCase.get(whereToPut) != null) {
                whereToPut = retrieveIndex(whereToPut, currentIndexToPreviousIndexMapping);
            }
            worstCase.set(whereToPut, reverseOrdered.get(inOrderCount));
            currentIndexToPreviousIndexMapping.put(whereToPut, worstCase.size() - inOrderCount - 1);
            inOrderCount++;
        }
        return worstCase;
    }
    
    public static <E extends Comparable<? super E>> void quickSortUsingMiddlePivot(List<E> input, List<Integer> partitionIndexHistory) {
        if (input == null || input.isEmpty()) {
            return;
        }
        quickSortUsingMiddlePivot(input, 0, input.size() - 1, partitionIndexHistory);
    }
    
    private static int retrieveIndex(int currentIndex, Map<Integer, Integer> currentIndexToPreviousIndexMapping) {
        if (!currentIndexToPreviousIndexMapping.containsKey(currentIndex)) {
            return currentIndex;
        }
        return retrieveIndex(currentIndexToPreviousIndexMapping.get(currentIndex), currentIndexToPreviousIndexMapping);
    }
}
```

I've conducted a simple test, and it has passed. However, I'm uncertain about the accuracy of my approach.

```java
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import java.util.*;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;
import static worstcasegenerator.WorstCaseForMiddlePivotQuickSort.generateWorstCaseForQuickSortPivotPoint;
import static worstcasegenerator.WorstCaseForMiddlePivotQuickSort.quickSortUsingMiddlePivot;

class WorstCaseForMiddlePivotQuickSortTest {
    
    private List<Integer> generatePrefixSizeList(int size) {
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= size; i++) {
            list.add(i);
        }
        return list;
    }
    
    private void checkIfIsWorstCase(List<Integer> partitionIndexHistory, int size) {
        assertEquals(size - 1, partitionIndexHistory.size());
        for (int i = 0; i < partitionIndexHistory.size(); i++) {
            assertEquals(size - 1 - i, partitionIndexHistory.get(i));
        }
    }
    
    @Test
    void testWorstCaseForMiddlePivotQuickSortGenerator() {
        for (int size = 1; size <= 100; size++) {
            List<Integer> testInput = generatePrefixSizeList(size);
            List<Integer> partitionIndexHistory = new ArrayList<>();
            Map<Integer, Integer> currentIndexToPreviousIndexMapping = new HashMap<>();
            List<Integer> worstCase = generateWorstCaseForQuickSortPivotPoint(testInput, currentIndexToPreviousIndexMapping);
            System.out.println("input size: " + size + " , worst case input : " + worstCase);
            quickSortUsingMiddlePivot(worstCase, partitionIndexHistory);
            System.out.println("partition index history: " + partitionIndexHistory);
            checkIfIsWorstCase(partitionIndexHistory, size);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm seeking feedback on correctness and potential improvements for this solution. Specifically, I'd like insights into optimizing the algorithm, improving code readability, etc.

Any feedback, suggestions, or improvements would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

## cite your reference

There is a rich literature on QuickSort.
Pick an author and cite the work.

Preferably work that includes worst case analysis,
so we don't need a second citation,
and so there's consistent notation throughout.

## write down loop variants

Also pre- and post- conditions.

You don't *have* to throw an error
if caller of `partition()` passed in some `low > high` parameters,
but it *would* improve clarity.
Especially for the case of `low == high` -- is it OK for caller to do that?
The code can tell the Gentle Reader that,
and seeing such an error during interactive testing might quickly reveal an
[OBOB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error),
saving you some debugging effort.
I know, I know, I see a caller making an `if (low >= high) {` test.
What I'm shooting for is Local Analysis,
being able to reason about a function in isolation, understanding the
[promises](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_by_contract)
involved.
The author's goal should be to make it easy
for the Gentle Reader to reason about what's happening.

Within the loop, and/or at the end of `partition()`,
it would be nice to see a comment and/or assertion
describing what we guarantee upon exit.

Since `generateWorstCaseForQuickSortPivotPoint()`
covers less familiar ground, the above points
are especially relevant for that code.

## concise identifier

`whereToPut` isn't a *bad* identifier,
but it sounds like a temporary name
you meant to come back to and rename later.
Consider using a straightforward noun
like `worstLocation`.

## define a logging object

The `partitionIndexHistory` is a common parameter
that comes along for the ride throughout.
Which is a code smell.
The code is telling you that it wants you to
create a `Sorter` object with the history
as an attribute.
Then we can make the usual quicksort calls
without noisily drawing attention to the history log
which will be side effected.

## chatty test

`testWorstCaseForMiddlePivotQuickSortGenerator()`
sends many lines to stdout.
Prefer to make automated unit tests succeed silently,
displaying Green Bar rather than Red.